# user draws a picture as input in R and program measures it's length

Tags: r

I need a program which will at one point open a MS-Paint likewindow, where the user will draw a horizontal line with themouse pointer (which probably would not be a proper "straight" line) and the program will give the length of the line as output (i.e. the distancebetween left-most point and right most point).

Is it possible to do something like this (or atleast something close enough) in R? If not, is there any other language where one can do this by simple programs? Thanks.

Comment: probably not.  This will probably get closed, but can you give a little more context?  `?locator` might be helpful.

Comment: Oh. Then, is possible to get a paint like window in any other language you know?

Comment: @santanu did my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Using `locator` as Ben suggested.

```
    lengthline<-function(){
x11()
plot(1:10,type="n",ylab="",xlab="")
ypoints<-locator(n=2,type="o")
x1<-min(ypoints$x)
x2<-max(ypoints$x)
y1<-min(ypoints$y)
y2<-max(ypoints$y)
x=x2-x1
y=y2-y1
leng<-sqrt(x^2+y^2)
mtext(paste("Length = ",leng,sep=""),3, line=1,font=4)
return(leng)
}
lengthline() #Calling the function.
```

Window should pop up and as soon as you click twice a line will be drawn and `lingthline` will return the length of the line.
If you want a nicer looking line you can play with graphic parameters i.e.
 `ypoints<-locator(n=2,type="o",col="red",lwd=2)`. You could also change `type` to `type="n"` and take the values x and y and draw the line manually.

Comment: You took a difficult-sounding problem and gave a simple, straightforward answer. Nice job!

Comment: Thanks! This should work just fine. I will try it tomorrow. Sorry, I could not comment to thank you earlier. My reputation was too low.

Comment: Great! If this works for you please select as best answer. Glad I could help.